# Heroku bash on windows

Tags: python, bash, shell, heroku, ipython

I am trying to connect to Heroku bash on windows and use `python manage.py shell` iPython shell to help me type commands faster.

While this works fine if I am on Mac, on my Windows machine - the colour coding of heroku bash iPython shell and the tab-autocomplete feature does not work.

Is there some other tool I can use or can configure somewhere? I tried installing bash on Windows, and it gives me the same result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT, *NOT*, **NOT**!!@!!!!! be using Heroku's bash shell for casual python coding. This is an awful idea for many reasons:

- Heroku dynos don't have a persistent filesystem. Any files on your dyno can be deleted randomly.
- The amount of time it will take you to build an ipython setup / configuration from scratch, and get it running on your dyno is not worth the effort.
- Heroku dynos are meant to run web processes as they restart randomly -- your terminal session may blow up at any point.

If you really want an authentic 'shell' experience, I recommend using a real shell for development -- either get yourself a virtual machine and install ubuntu, or spin up a ubuntu server machine through a host like [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) or [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/).